# Merged with deleted question

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-questions, merged-questions

I found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4143371/995926) which was merged with [a deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4142049/dispaly-video-in-listview). I think [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4143371/995926) is now pointless and should be deleted too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Agreed. The stub has also been removed. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I cleaned up the other three that were merged into that deleted question as well.

Comment: @AnnaLear Hai, good _gawd_. Yeah, that'll teach me to check histories before calling it done.