# Answer deleted by moderator after the question was merged

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, deleted-answers, merged-questions

See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20674425/1923685). (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20674425/1923685)

Actually I gave this answer for the Stack Overflow question *[How to compare μ and µ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674300/how-to-compare-and-in-c-sharp/20674425#20674425)*. The answer was trying to describe how both characters were different and why they weren't equal. It was relevant for that question and got 37 upvotes for the same.

Later, the original question was merged with [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20674577/how-to-compare-unicode-characters-that-look-alike/) which was asked by the same OP later (this question directly asks about the problem). This merging made the answer somewhat irrelevant. Later, that answer was deleted, and the added reputation got removed.

Why should the reputation be removed? I got the reputation for a faster response and relevant answer, right? Can I get that reputation back?

Comment: It seems like you have a valid case here, and I assume a moderator will be with you shortly. In the meantime,  relax. I'd suggest you return to your original, more sensible question title.

Comment: Undeleted. Merge-related confusion! (I can't help with the justice, though...)

Comment: @AndrewBarber Justice because, my answer was deleted for a reason that I were not responsible. And I need the reputation back for the same. Thank you!

Comment: @AndrewBarber Sometimes you might not have a tool that could remove answer without removing its reputation gains.

Comment: When I go to that answer, it is shown as having a score of 37.  If those are nonetheless not contributing to your reputation value, then you may need a rep recalc.

Comment: Jeez, calm down, no need to **SHOUT**. And does every other answer that doesn't already offer a code solution really have to piggyback off my answer?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I removed the section I added.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vote to delete answers as duplicates of earlier answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243243/282094) the *priority* is: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/53136/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113707/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/159835/282094

Answer (score -1):

I (OP of this question) got my answer undeleted. The moderator responded and reverted the action. I admit that my answer became irrelevant and won't match the question any more after the merge. However, I'm not responsible for the case, and I have the right for those reputation point gains.

It would be better if a moderator could remove an answer without removing the reputation.

Comment: The problem with removing an answer without removing the reputation from votes is that when an answer is deleted, it should not have existed in the first place, so neither should the reputation gained from upvotes or lost from downvotes. Answers > 60 days old are exempt from this, but that's a different issue. Of course, now that the answer is undeleted the reputation will remain. In fact, since we can undelete answers that were wrongfully deleted, thereby restoring the rep gained from it, there really isn't any point in having an option to retain rep when deleting a relatively young answer.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn so if I understand correctly answers deleted after 60 days won't effect reputation?

Comment: @Shafik: Correct.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. It was an incredibly silly rule change designed to appease those whining the loudest.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn is there a thread that covers this? I searched a bit but could not come up with anything.

Comment: @Shafik http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/reputation-and-historical-archives/